# Proving that $\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\{a_n+b_n\}\neq \sup\limits_{n\geq 1}a_n+\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\{a_n\}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\{b_n\},\;\;n=1,2,3,...$ be bounded subsets of real numbers, then
>
> $$\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\{a_n+b_n\}\leq \sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\{a_n\}+\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\{b_n\}$$

The proof of the above is trivial. However if $A=\{a_n\},\;\;B=\{b_n\}$ and $A+B=\{a_n+b_n\}$ then, I wish to prove that

> $$\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\{a_n+b_n\}\neq \sup\limits_{n\geq 1}a_n+\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}b_n$$

Please, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

Take $$a_n:=(-1)^{n}
\ \ \text{ and }\ \ b_n:=(-1)^{n-1}$$ so that $$\sup_n \{a_n+b_n\}=0$$ and $$\sup_n \{a_n\}+\sup_n\{b_n\}=2$$

Comment: @ Shashi: Please can you use these sequences $\{a_n\}:=\{(-1)\}$ and $\{b_n\}:=\{\dfrac{1}{n}\}$?

Comment: @Mike If you mean $a_n=(-1)^n$, then yes the sequences you provided work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I meant $a_n=(−1)^n$ instead of $a_n=(−1)$.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I might have misinterpreted something, but the sequences you provided satisfy the equality you wanted, but do not work as a counterexample. That is what I actually meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \{ a_n \} = \{ 1,0,1,0,1,0,.....\}\implies \sup \{a_n\} = 1$$

$$\{ b_n\} = \{ 0,1,0,1,0,1,.....\}\implies \sup\{ b_n\} = 1 $$

$$\{a_n +b_n\} =\{ 1,1,1,1,1,.....\}\implies \sup\{ a_n + b_n\} = 1 $$

$$ 1\ne 1+1 $$